Staging Ground review allows choosing both "upvote when posted on main site" and "vote as off-topic" at the same time
Please refer to the below screenshot:

While reviewing a question in Staging Ground, the user interface allows the reviewer to 'upvote when posted on main site' even though the reviewer is voting as off-topic.
This does not make sense.
I am aware that it is an option (as the UI says - "Additional Options"). Of course, whether to check the upvote check-box is the reviewer's choice, and they are not forced to do so. Still, the two actions are opposite. If the reviewer is willing to interact with the post "negatively", the "positive" interactions does not make sense and should be disabled.

In a perfect world, choosing any of the last 3 radio buttons would disable that option, but calling that a bug is kinda farfetched. If it takes more than an hour to fix that, I'd rather prioritize other tasks.

I think it would make more sense to just have "Approve and post with an upvote" as one of the radio-button options, instead of the checkbox.

IMO using the "Requires Major Changes" or no option at all with the "Add an upvote when posted on the main site" checkbox can make sense in some cases.

Could it perhaps make sense to express something to the effect of "I think this question is off-topic, but if other reviewers believe I'm mistaken about that, it's a good question"?
